# What HTML is permitted within Flash text fields

Tags: html, flash

Could someone clarify for me what input Flash accepts for its text fields?

I am tasked with managing a content management system, this then generates XML which power's flash sites. I have nothing to do with Flash. I work with PHP. Currently we use a rather temperamental Flash Text Editor which is prone to all sorts of troubles.

I tried to plug-in tinyMce but it broke the Flash templates. I then recently spoke to someone who said that flash should take any HTML. Now I am confused as this would point to a dodgy template.

Can someone clarify. Do Flash text fields handle all HTML or just a limited subset of HTML. If it is the latter, what happens if it comes across a tag it doesn't recognise? Does it display the tag or break?

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see [this page](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText) for a list, but be warned, some things (br, p in particular) might not function exactly the way you think. for example i had an issue where an img with a br after it did not move the next line of text down correctly, it floated it on the right of the text instead.

edit: also be aware that if you allow bold and italics tags and you're using an embedded font, then you'll need to embed the bold and italic forms too.

Comment: Thanks, so do I need to filter the user input to strip incompatible tags? If so are you aware of any text editor that only uses the flash subset of HTML?

Comment: i think the flash textfield renderer will just ignore unsupported tags so you shouldn't need to filter them out. and maybe in the future it'll support more, so imho it's best to leave them in anyway.